# No module named pandas.core.indexes.numeric error while doing Randomized search CV for Random Forest algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

```py
param={'n_estimators':[100,200,300]}
rf_Model = RandomForestVlassifier()
ran = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rf_Model,param_distributions=param,cv=5,verbose=2)
```

Getting error as

```
No module named pandas.core.indexes.numeric
```

Comment: This code works well for me. I don't understand why you have this error. Can you provide the full traceback of the exception, please?

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, are you running `pandas 2.0` ?

Check out this

```
import pandas
print(pandas.__version__)
```

This new version is a major release and is hot off the press. It broke countless other libraries. You will need to be careful about versions of libraries. Using a package manager like `conda` will probably save you a lot of headache and allows you to focus on actual work.